# How to append ajax response into <tr>

Tags: php, ajax, html-table

I have a table in which the data is coming from a database, and the table has a lots of `<tr>` tags. With each `<tr>` tag I am fixing the "+" sign and want to retrieve the response from Ajax by clicking on to this "+". Can you  please tell me how to achieve this using Ajax?

Here is my code of table on which the "+" is coming:

```
<table id=\"table_$author_id\" width=\"100%\">
                    <TR bgColor=#F5F5F5>
                        <TD class=normaltext hight=35 align=center><div id=\"test_$author_id\" class=\"test\" style=\"display:inline\">+</div><div id=\"aid_$author_id\" class=\"aid\" style=\"display:inline\">$author_id</div></TD>
                        <TD class=normaltext align=left>$author_name</TD>
                        <TD class=normaltext align=center><a href=\"author_edit.php?aid=$author_id&mode=edit\">Edit</a></TD>
                        <TD class=normaltext align=center><a href=\"author_finance.php?aid=$author_id\">Edit</a></TD>
                        <TD class=normaltext align=center><a href=\"author_list_admin.php?aid=$author_id&mode=delete\">Delete</a></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <table>
```

I tried this code for ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.test').click(function(){

            var URL = 'bangkokbooks/php/admin/author_ajax_detail.php';
            console.log(this.id);
            var ID = this.id;
            var arr= ID.split('_');
            var author_id=arr[1];
            console.log(author_id);

            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "author_ajax_detail.php",
                                data: "&author_id="+author_id,
                                success: function(html){                

                                            console.log(html);
                                            $('#table_'+author_id).append(html); 
                                      }
                                }); 

        });


    });
```

But by this way my alignment is horribly disturbed.
Now please tell me how can I add the response below the each `<tr>` tag, or tell me the another way to do it.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Have you done any tutorials?

Comment: @WayneWhitty, you can see my updated question.i used table id to achieve it.but its alignment is disturb.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class or an ID to your `<tr>`-tag and use jQuery to append new content to your `<tr>`. That's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is not correct :

```
<table id="table_authorId" width="100%">
                    <TR bgColor='#F5F5F5'>
                        <TD class='normaltext' height=35 align='center'><div id="test_$author_id" class="test" style="display:inline">+</div><div id="aid_$author_id" class="aid" style="display:inline">$author_id</div></TD>
                        <TD class=normaltext align=left>$author_name</TD>
                        <TD class=normaltext align=center><a href="author_edit.php?aid=$author_id&mode=edit">Edit</a></TD>
                        <TD class=normaltext align=center><a href="author_finance.php?aid=$author_id">Edit</a></TD>
                        <TD class=normaltext align=center><a href="author_list_admin.php?aid=$author_id&mode=delete">Delete</a></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <table>​
```

Add php quotes as per your requirement. And add following jQuery.ajax success callback :

```
jQuery.ajax({
   ........
     success: function(response){
          ......
          $('#table_authorId').append("<tr><td colspan =5>"+response+"</td></tr>");​
          .......................
     }
 });
```

Here is an example with constant data : http://jsfiddle.net/aDcQm/1/